# How to provide run time parameters in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I created one  (using jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler) script for UI login using a single user. Now I want to log in to 100 different users with different credentials. How we can achieve this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases people put credentials into a [.CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and read them using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) for JMeter tests parameterization.

If you need to use a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in the WebDriver Sampler script you can use `WDS.vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
var user = WDS.vars.get('username')
var pass = WDS.vars.get('password')

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('someId')).sendKeys(user)
//etc.
```